# Check for a server response on a specific port Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Say I wanted to show a user if a service was running on a certain port at a web address or IP address.

What could I use for code that would be acceptable in the Apple Developer Program?

iOS is the target Platform.

Comment: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use
Check this part :
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
  ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request startSynchronous];
  NSError *error = [request error];
  if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
  }